# react-native transform error couldn't find preset "react-native"

Tags: react-native

When running a react-native app in development mode, after starting npm server. when the app requests the bundle package it gives this error,

[image]

```
The development server returned response error code:500

URL: http://192.168.1.55:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&
     dev=true&hot=false&minify=false

Body:
 {"message":"TransformError:/var/www/html/test_projects/test/index.android.js: 

Couldn't find preset \"react-native\" relative to directory
\"/var/www/html/test_projects\"","type":"TransofrmError","errors":[{}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is occurred due to the incompatible react and react-native versions.
To get this working you have to install the correct react and react-native versions with following method.

eg.

```
npm install --force react@15.2.0
npm install --force react-native@0.28.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Check in your package.json file there react-native installed correctly or not. You can also create **.babelrc** file in root of you project with following content:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

Comment: `{"presets": ["react-native", "react"]}` could help